# neonatal syntax acquisition

Tags: syntax, language-acquisition

How do infants use the patterns of distribution among closed class words to acquire syntax?  Has anyone simulated the process?  If we start formulating our theories as we begin to recognize words, and we come to recognize the highest frequency words first, then I guess infants then start noticing high frequency bigrams.  How do we get from bigrams to compositional constructions?

  3.

Comment: Infants? Almost all the closed class words are reduced or omitted most of the time in ordinary speech. They are among the last words acquired by top-down learners, not the first.

Comment: I keep reading about how infants recognize syntactic patterns before they begin to speak. Is it thought that they do so without first coming to recognize closed-class words (in languages that employ them)?